# Using OpenAM to create/configure a fedlet for a Java application

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, openam

I was tasked with allowing Single Sign On in a java application hosted on a weblogic server.

I have read that a fedlet can do federation in your service provider application with OpenAM acting as the identity provider.  That honestly sounds like exactly what I need.  Is that correct?

If so, how do I get started?  I have done some research on the OpenAM site, and it keeps mentioning doing things through the admin console.  Do I need to download openAM onto a server before creating the fedlet?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The common task to create a Fedlet-based sample application is provided via OpenAM console. Therefor you would need to setup OpenAM and configure it as a SAML IdP. The OpenAM zip-Distro also includes an unconfigued Fedlet-based sample app. The Fedlet is actually only a collection of libs and SAML meta-data and will handle the low-level SAML stuff for you. It won't provide the integration with your app out of the box. You may be better off using the Spring security SAML extension as this provides easier integration with an existing Java-based Web Application. Also, depending on the Weblogic version used, WLS also provides a SAMLv2 SP. you may check https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13707/saml.htm#SECMG279

Comment: Thank you for this comment, I believe I have weblogic set up as a SP.  What would my next step be?  I know I need my IDP's metadata file, but they sent it as a .ashx file

Comment: OpenAM does not provide '.ashx' files the should export the standard metadata with OpenAM console or 'ssoadm export-entity ...'. SAML meta data are XML documents.

You then need to export your meta and provide them to the IdP guys.

If you are using signature/encryption you may need to create a proper keypair.

Comment: Sorry, I should mention that I am no longer using OpenAM.  I have simply set up weblogic as a SP, and imported PortalGuard's (my IdP) metadata into weblogic.... they finally sent me an xml version.  Now I would like to test my changes.  Can this be done by simply linking my submit form to the IdP URL, and sending some xml data as a parameter?